# What is the difference between -> and :: in PHP?

Tags: php, class, oop

This thing has been bugging me for long and I can't find it anywhere!

What is the difference when using classes in php between :: and ->

Let me give an example.

Imagine a class named MyClass and in this class there is a function myFunction

What is the difference between using:

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass
myclass::myFunction();
```

or

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass
myclass->myFunction();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as stated, "::" is for static method calls whereas "->" is for instance method calls

except for when using parent:: to access functions in a base class, where "parent::" can be used for both static and non-static parent methods

```
abstract class myParentClass
{
   public function foo()
   {
      echo "parent class";
   }
}

class myChildClass extends myParentClass
{
   public function bar()
   {
      echo "child class";
      parent::foo();
   }
}

$obj = new myChildClass();
$obj->bar();
```

Answer (score 11):

```
MyClass::myFunction();  // static method call

$myclass->myFunction(); // instance method call
```

Comment: So, does `myclass::myFunction();` compile, and if so, what does it mean?

Comment: I just tried it and $myclass::myFunction() doesn't parse in php - which is good since by definition the static method should not be allowed to be executed from an instance.

Comment: That makes sense, but you never know with PHP... :)

Answer (score 3):

"::" is for calling static methods on the class. So, you can use:

```
MyClass::myStaticFunction()
```

but not:

```
MyClass->myStaticFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass {
  static function myStaticFunction(...){
  ...
  }

}

//$myObject=new MyClass(); it isn't necessary. It's true??

MyClass::myStaticFunction();
```