# What is the difference between this two methods for initializing a PHP class?

Tags: php, class

i would like to know the difference between this two methods for initializing the object of a class

Method 1 (Using Scope resolution operator) :

```
Test::foo();
```

Method 2 (creating an instance of an object):

```
$test = new Test;
$test->foo();
```

also what is this `->` operator called?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between -> and :: in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804187/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Test::foo()` is merely statically calling a method of a class, it doesn't do anything with objects. It might *initialize* static values in the class, but you don't usually use static initializers. A static initializer may be used internally in the case of [Singletons](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php), but you should never call a public static initializer like this.

`$test = new Test` is actually *instantiating* an object, in which process it is likely *initialized*.

Please note the difference between *initialize* (setting up the initial state of an object/class/variable) and *instantiate* (create an object instance from a class).

`->` is the `T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`.

Comment: To add to this, you usually use static initializers if you're dealing with a singleton.

Comment: @Ibrahim, a singleton is where you can only have a single instance of a class at any given time. You can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php)

Comment: @Marcus Indeed, and to further add: In singletons this would just be an internal call, you wouldn't usually just statically call a method like this to initialize a class.

Comment: @deceze, would be great if you added this to your answer to further spread the knowledge ;)

Answer (score 2):

`::` is called "Paamayim Nekudotayim" (it's hebrew), `->` is the object operator:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Neither should be used to initialize your class. There's a magic `__construct()` method for that, which is called automatically by the `new` operator:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

`Test::foo()` means call method `foo()` statically, outside of the scope of an actual object. Think of it as some kind of (slow) namespaced function.

`$test->foo()` means call method `foo()` for object $test.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Answer (score 1):

You need lear oop ([Object Oriented Programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), and this implementation on PHP

The functions inside of classes, are called methods, this methods can be called on an instance of the class, or in static mode, The first call, don't create an instance of class*, this called the method 'foo' static.

```
class Test {

    public static $static_atribute;
    public $normal_atribute;

    public function Foo($q) {
         $this->normal_atribute = $q;
    }

    public static function SFoo ($q) {
         // I dont can access to $this
         self::$static_atribute = $q;
    }

}

Test::Foo("hello");
// This thrown an error because $this dont exist in static mode

Test::SFoo("hello");
//This works, and the static property change

echo Test::$static_atribute;
// this puts "hello"

echo Test::$normal_atribute;
// this thrown an error

$a = new Test();
// $a is an instance of Test

$a->foo("hello");
// this works and the normal_atribute change in THIS instance

$b = new Test();
// $b is anoter instance of Test

$b->foo("bye");
// normal_atribute change in THIS instance

echo $a->normal_atribute;
// puts hello

echo $b->normal_atribute;
// puts bye
```

- There is a pattern in which sused. called [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Answer (score -1):

I call it an arrow... but the difference is that with the arrow method, you're creating a new instance of that class as an object, which can then be referenced as an object. The other one simply calls a certain method of a certain class. With the object, you can store properties and call functions and store things in that object, and you can call multiple instances of that object and use them all separately... I'm rambling but there are tons of things you can do with an object that are limited with only calling the individual method.